# how use nuxtjs/moment in nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs3

this warining-> Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

Comment: This is not a warning related to Nuxt3, please make a simple search before posting. Also, I recommend not using moment because it's dead, so let it go already.

Comment: MomentJs is dead? why do you think so? and what alternative do you recommend?

Comment: @HakimBaheddi https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Comment: @HakimBaheddi  Use DayJs instead